# I am Brasilian resident, how to buy shares on NYSE?

Tags: investing, brazil

I am having my work contract here in Brasil. I have some money (3000$) and I would like to invest it in some specific companies that are listed on NYSE. How can I do this, it seems that most brokerage houses do not allow Brazilian residents to buy shares. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Many brokers do accept international customers (Interactive Brokers does), Brazilians should be accepted as well. Have you tried them?

Comment: This is definitely on-topic for PF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some brokers in the US who would be happy to open an account for non-US residents, allowing you to trade stocks at NYSE and other US Exchanges.

Some of them, along with some facts:

**DriveWealth**

- Competitive brokerage fees
- Process for account opening is straightforward and fast
- Mobile app is cool
- Has support in Portuguese
- [Website](https://drivewealth.com/home)

**TD Ameritrade**

- Moderate fees for shares
- Zero brokerage fees for some ETFs
- Has support in Portuguese

  [Website](https://www.tdameritrade.com/home.page)

**Interactive Brokers**

- Competitive brokerage fees
- Competitive margin account rates
- Access to some other major venues such as DAX (Germany), London, etc
- Account opening is not that straightforward

  [Website](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/home.php)

Answer (score 1):

There are ETFs listed on the Brazilian stock market. Specifically there is one for [S&P500](http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/en_us/products/listed-equities-and-derivatives/variable-income/etf/variable-income/etfs-listed/) - SPXI11, which might fulfill your requirements, though as one commenter has observed, it doesn't answer your original question.

Comment: The question talks about "shares" and "some companies that are listed" on the New York Stock Exchange. Unless there is a significant language barrier involved (which frankly it doesn't look like to me), that seems a poor match for an investment vehicle that targets the whole S&P 500 index.

Comment: Yes, I've got you and you are right the OP does specify shares and companies. I'm just giving an option that may help or give an insight into something they can do. Sometimes it is one idea that sparks off another, that gives the final solution. It is possible they just want to be able to hedge with the $US.

Comment: If OP wants to hedge against currency risk, that's a very different question and stock market investments are generally a very poor answer; a money market fund targetting the US would likely be better in that case. But that is drifting quite far from at least my reading of the question *and* this answer, so for everyone's sanity I'll drop this here.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Actually I thought of buying some oilservice industry shares. I think now it is good time to buy(of course if these companies survive these low oil prices)

Comment: @MikiBelavista I have proposed an edit to your question to try to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what a Brazilian equivalent is but you could just do an  [ADR](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/adr.asp). Keep in mind that when you are investing in a foreign company there are certain currency risks that you may need to consider.

Comment: There are BDRs - "Brazilian Depositary Receipts" listed in Brazil, problems are: 1. Access to most of them is limited to "Qualified Investors"; 2. Low liquidity might be a concern